Displaying Email with CID Referenced Images in Outlook VSTO Web Form
I am working on an Outlook VSTO project where I need to display emails as HTML within a web form. However, images referenced by CID are not displaying correctly. To resolve this, I downloaded the images to temporary files.
The code works for images attached to the email but fails for images used in signatures. How can I ensure that all CID-referenced images, including those in signatures, are displayed correctly?
these are my methods to extract HTML body and save to the temp file
        public string EmailBodyToHtml(MailItem mi)
    {
        string htmlBody = mi.HTMLBody;
        var result = mi.HTMLBody;
        Regex reg = new Regex(@"<img[^>]*src=[""']cid:(?<cid>[^""']+)[""'][^>]*>");
        var matches = reg.Matches(htmlBody);
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            string cid = match.Groups["cid"].Value;
            string tempFile = SaveInlineImageToTcempFile(mi, cid);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tempFile))
            {
                result = result.Replace($"cid:{cid}", tempFile);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

        private string SaveInlineImageToTcempFile(MailItem mi, string cid)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (Attachment item in mi.Attachments)
            {
                PropertyAccessor pa = item.PropertyAccessor;
             string attCid=""+   pa.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F") as string;
                if (attCid!=null && attCid.ToLower()==cid.ToLower())
                {
                    string tempFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), item.FileName);
                    item.SaveAsFile(tempFile);
                    return tempFile;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            var msg = e.Message;
           
        }
        return null;
    }

the error I'm getting the exception for signatures is "Cannot save the attachment. Cannot add the attachment; no data source was provided."

Anything special about the problematic attachments? What are their filenames? Are you sure item.FileName is not an empty string?

No it's not an empty string the file name is correct with fike extension it's look like any other cid format
